# my own customizations of boot2docker are not reflected into the iso image

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Following the section at [Making your own customised boot2docker ISO](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md), i wrote the Dockerfile below to install the vim package:

```
FROM boot2docker/boot2docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

RUN /make_iso.sh

CMD ["cat", "boot2docker.iso"]
```

Then executed these commands successfully:

```
docker build -t my-boot2docker-img . && docker run --rm my-boot2docker-img > boot2docker.iso
```

I created a virtual machine using this iso image and logged into it. I've expected the vim is now available on my shell but it was not. From the build process console logs, i saw the vim installed successfully. However it is apparently not included in the iso.

Can someone please tell me, what i've missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only installed vim in the build container that produces the final boot2docker iso. To get the desired result you need to install any packages/data at `$ROOTFS` in the build container. For some hints on how to accomplish this with `apt-get` see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory).

But first you should ask yourself why you need vim in a VM that is only meant as a transparent proxy for mac/windows users.

#### Edit:

As you got valid reasons to build your own boot2docker iso, have a look at the [boot2docker repo](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker).

The [dockerfile](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) broken down:

1. install build dependencies in the build container
2. download and compile a linux kernel with aufs support, copy to `$ROOTFS`
3. download and extract [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/) distribution at `$ROOTFS`
4. download and extract [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/) packages defined in `$TCZ_DEPS` to `$ROOTFS`
5. build and install VMware tools and other helpers at `$ROOTFS`
6. export `$ROOTFS` as new iso

I'd probably look into extending on [step 4](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L135) first, i.e. simply download packages from the TinyCore repo.

Comment: vim was the first package came to my mind. it was only for test purposes. I am going to install samba to mount windows shares (i run boot2docker on hyper-v, thus there is no built-in feature).

Comment: i read the docker-machine docs. However, i must have missed the section, which clarifies the "build container" & "$ROOTFS" relation. Can you please point me to a link? Better, if you happen to know, to a more concrete example. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I have started to understand the process. I actually have already looked at the Dockerfile at boot2docker repo. It was the apt-get part at the beginning, which misled me. Thanks again.